# Terminologia "Orientado a objeto"

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags

Coloquei aqui pois é mais uma questão linguística.

Qual é o termo correto para uma linguagem que usa somente objetos (C#), e uma linguagem que usa objetos, mas não é completamente baseada neles.

Exemplo: O VB tem (tinha) diversas funções que não estavam em objetos, e um suporte (limitado) a OOP. Acho que o C++ é assim também. Existem termos certos para isso?

Eu me lembro de ver essa diferença de classificação (entre linguagens object-enabled [VB] e linguagens baseadas em objeto [C#]), mas não onde.

(Estou perguntando pois vi isso em tags, e não sei se está correto. Mais específicamente - a tag VBA diz "orientado a objetos". Acho que VBA suporta objetos (de forma limitada), mas não é orientada a objetos. Queria confirmar antes de alterar)

Comment: O pior é que eu acho que não encaixa aqui também. O Meta como o próprio nome diz é para debater o SOpt e não outros assuntos que não se encaixam nele. Se souber escrever a pergunta (sem querer debate), ela cabe no SOpt. Sua premissa do que é objeto e do que é orientado a objeto realmente está errada. E o termo é usado de forma errada o tempo todo.

Comment: @bigown Achei que valia por serem termos usados nas descrições das tags... Quis perguntar antes de alterar a tag.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101 leia o comentário. Eu fiz algo assim. Eu acho que o termo não é uma questão do funcionamento do site. Se devemos consertar o conteúdo errado seria uma questão para debater aqui. Mas sei a resposta já: devemos consertar qualquer informação errada.

Comment: Eu teria arrumado... mas não tenho certeza :)

Comment: A resposta está aqui: [Orientado a objeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos). Orientado a objeto vs com suporte a objeto. Vou alterar a tag.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown.... Se for reescrita, é uma pergunta perfeitamente cabível no site

Comment: Feito. Removo essa aqui?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101